# Transition effect (common material to grid material)

Tags: materials, node-editor, compositing-nodes, effects

Please tell me how i can achieve this transition effect. Only Compositing? Or can this effect be achieved in another way? Suppose I want to apply this transition effect to only one mesh in the scene.
[image: transition effect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, compositing, you will have to assign the object to his own render layer, in order to treat it separately.

[image]